# How Can I Do a Fuzzy Character Merge using Hash Objects in SAS?

Tags: hash, sas, fuzzy-search

I'm testing out how to use hash objects in SAS 9.4 M6 to do fuzzy joins since PROC SQL just runs for hours on my larger dataset. I created some sample datasets (below) and what I want is for the merge to pull in exact matches on the "name" fields AND any matches that have a COMPLEV score less than 10. Right now, this code still only pulls in the exact matches.

I'm very new to hash objects so I'm sure it's a simple fix but I've tried am in need of help.

```
data A;
infile datalines missover;
length nameA $50;
input nameA $ ;
datalines;
MICKEYMOUSE2000-01-02
DAFDUCK1990-09-23
GOOFYMAN1993-05-11
;
run;

*second dataset with one exact match and two that differ slightly from those in dataset A;
data B;
infile datalines missover;
length nameB $50;
input nameB $ VDAY :ddmmyy10.;
format VDAY ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
MICKEYMOUSE2000-01-01 07/08/2021
DAFFYDUCK1990-09-23 05/11/2021
GOOFYMAN1993-05-11 08/11/2021
;
run;

*only pulling in exact matches, want it to pull in other fuzzy matches;

data simplemerge ;

if 0 then set work.B ; *load var properties into hash table;

if _n_ = 1 then do;
    dcl hash B (dataset: 'work.B'); *declare the name B for hash using B dataset;
    B.definekey('nameB');*identify var in B to use as key;
    B.definedata('nameB','vday');*identify columns of data to bring in from B dataset;
    B.definedone();*complete hash table definition;
end;

set work.A; *bring in A data;

if B.Find(KEY: nameA) ne 0 then do;
        if complev(nameA, nameB) < 10 then do;
            B.ref(key : nameB,data : nameB, data : vday);
        end;
end;

RUN;
```

Comment: In hash you can only search for exact terms if you would like to search for similar strings you should use some sort of tree but these are not implemented in SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy match in hash is not necessarily better than SQL - in fact, good chance it's identical.  SQL joins are often done with a hash table behind the scenes.

That said, here's how you'd do the naive hash fuzzy lookup - with a hash iterator (`hiter`).

```
data simplemerge ;

if 0 then set work.B ; *load var properties into hash table;

if _n_ = 1 then do;
    dcl hash B (dataset: 'work.B'); *declare the name B for hash using B dataset;
    B.definekey('nameB');*identify var in B to use as key;
    B.definedata('nameB','vday');*identify columns of data to bring in from B dataset;
    B.definedone();*complete hash table definition;
    dcl hiter hi_b('B');
end;

set work.A; *bring in A data;

done = 0;

if B.Find(KEY: nameA) ne 0 then do;

   rc = hi_b.first();
   do while (rc eq 0 ); 
    if complev(nameA, nameB) lt 10 then do;
        put "Found one!" namea= nameb=;    
        leave;
    end;
    else call missing(of nameB vday);   
    rc = hi_b.next();
   end;
end;
else put "Found one!" namea=;

RUN;
```

This will be ... not fast ... if `work.B` has a lot of rows.  It goes over every row of `B` once for every row of `A` that doesn't have an exact match.

One thing you *can* do to make this more efficient is not search all of `B`.  Instead, have some smaller subset of `B` that you find *with* an exact match, and then iterate over that smaller subset; instead of using `hiter` just use the `find_next`.  This may not work for your exact requirements, but if it's feasible, this would be ideal.

Here's one example of doing that.  It's not particularly efficient since `sex` has only two values (so I'm looking through half of the rows anyway), but it does work.

```
data have;
  set sashelp.class;
  if mod(_n_,3) eq 0 then do;
    name = cats(name,'Z');
  end;
  if mod(_n_,5) eq 0 then do;
    name = cats('Row_',_n_);
  end;
run;

data want;
  if 0 then set sashelp.classfit;
  length name_fuzz $8;
  *first define two hash tables - one for exact match, one for fuzzy.  Only do this if exact matches are reasonably common;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    declare hash h_exact(dataset:'sashelp.classfit');
    h_exact.defineKey('name');
    h_exact.defineData(all:'Y');
    h_exact.defineDone();
    
    declare hash h_fuzzy(dataset:'sashelp.classfit(rename=name=name_fuzz keep=name sex predict lower upper lowermean uppermean)',multidata:'y');
    h_fuzzy.defineKey('sex');
    h_fuzzy.defineData(all:'Y');
    h_fuzzy.defineDone();  
    call missing(name_fuzz);
  end;
  
  set have;
  *now check exact - if it matches then do not try further;
  rc_exact = h_exact.find();
  if rc_exact eq 0 then do;
    output;
    return;
  end;
  
  *now try fuzzy - first look up the first match by the chunk criteria;
  rc_fuzzy = h_fuzzy.find();
  *now iterate over all of the matches of the chunk, and if you find a close-enough match then output that row and stop trying;
  do while (rc_fuzzy eq 0);           
    if complev(name,name_fuzz) lt 2 then do;
        output;
        return;
    end;
    rc_fuzzy = h_fuzzy.find_next();
  end;
  *if you are still here, you failed to find a fuzzy match - so clear the values from the variables you are merging on and output a blank row, assuming you are doing a "left join" [if it is inner join, then just skip these next two lines];
  call missing(of predict lower upper lowermean uppermean);
  output;
run;
```

A better version of this would have a more discriminating key for the fuzzy match - the more discriminating the better.  The key might not be something related at all to your fuzzy match - for example, maybe your fuzzy match is looking for names, but you also their year of birth.  Match on year of birth, then iterate over complev(namea,nameb), since year of birth is quite discriminating.